# Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found error in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Resource not found error while trying to send URL of change password to registered email. I have    checked the spelling and directories of my project. Everything is fine still I am getting that error.
 This is the URL for sending email to registered users.

```
sbemailBody.Append("http://localhost/VirtualClassroom/Register/changePassword.aspx?uid=" +     Uniqueid);
```

When i click this link,I am getting that error.I am new to .Net.Please help.Thanks in advance![image]

Comment: If you are trying to click on the link on a client, the problem is `localhost` since there is no `localhost` on the client machine (which receives the email)

Comment: I am testing with my mail id only.I have sent mail to my mail id,on clicking this URL from my own pc i get this error @RezaRahmati

Comment: what will happen if you copy and paste the generated url in your pc browser?

Comment: So is there any way to resolve it ? I am new to .net.please explain @RezaRahmati

Comment: I am trying to help, copy and paste the generated url in your browser and tell me the result

Comment: I tried it. Still I am getting the same error @RezaRahmati

Comment: So your url is incorrect, try `http://localhost/VirtualClassroom` to be sure your site exists

Comment: I checked it so many times.Its perfect still @RezaRahmati

Comment: So do you have `Register` folder under it? and if yes is there `changePassword.aspx` in `Register` folder? Please be sure about spelling.

Comment: Yea i have a folder and a webpage also. @RezaRahmati

Comment: Just paste this in your browser `http://localhost/VirtualClassroom/Register/changePassword.aspx` and tell me the result

Comment: Also add a screenshot of your file system which the site is located in your question. (open the windows explorer and go to the folder open it until you get to changePassword.aspx and take screen shot)

Comment: I have added screenshot of my project instead for getting clear idea.And i pasted URL of the link which you gave. Still i get the same error @RezaRahmati

Comment: is your site hosted to the IIS or you are using visual studio dev server(in debug mode)

Comment: No i didnot host in IIS. Its using default server @Pranav

Comment: that's the problem ... run your solution in visual studio .. see the URL and port number ... modify your Link with port number and ensure that when you click on the link in your mail , your visual studio dev server is running. :)

Comment: one more thing .. just for info .. your url should be something like this `http://localhost:12345/Register/changePassword.aspx?uid=" +     Uniqueid`  without any Virtual directory name (i.e. VirtualClassroom in your case, and port number can be diff.) if you are running in VS dev server only.

Comment: I dont get the port number when i run my application via IIS. Rather I am getting alias name given.This is the url generated when i run using IIs where virtualclass is a alias name given. http://localhost/virtualclass/Register/changePassword.aspx                              @Pranav

Comment: I now can open the link but its redirected to login.aspx web page in my application instead of opening changePassword.aspx @Pranav

Comment: Thanks a lot its working fine !! I made changes to my URL as you said.I removed my project name and included the port number. :-) and btw can u explain the reason why the error arised before.Ia am new to .Net @Pranav

Comment: Simple crust is Your server must be running for taking any request,hence if your application is hosted in IIS then it will take the virtual directory name, but VS dev server cassini is for development purpose only ... it internally knows what application you are running ..so no need of Virtual Dir name.. its tough to explain whole story .. just search and read about IIS and VS dev server cassini :)

Comment: What will happen if application is hosted on a website? Im planning to host on a website so am I supposed to modify URL accordingly. ? @Pranav